# Is there a name for "product divided by arithmetic mean"?

Tags: mean

Consider two rates, $0 < x, y < 1$. How would one call $z$, if

$z = \frac{x*y}{(x+y)/2} = \frac{2*x*y}{x+y}$?

Is there a relationship with other means, such as the [Inequality of arithmetic and geometric means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means)?

Comment: That quantity would be more likely to have a name if it were dimensionless i.e. if you took the square root of the numerator. Still not sure if it does, though.

Comment: @SideshowBob well, all the means (arithmetic, geometric, harmonic, median, ...) are not dimensionless, either :)

Comment: See [this article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2285338?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)?

Comment: This is called the *Harmonic Mean.*